# How to replace aweber oauth api 1.0 to oauth 2.0

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii-extensions, aweber

One of my website is using Aweber deprecated API (https://github.com/aweber/AWeber-API-PHP-Library), it was working fine previously but stopped, the implementation of this API has been done by another developer, now this website is handled by me and I never have worked with Aweber, may anyone help me to replace OAuth 1.0 to OAuth 2.0.

the error users receive after sign up is this.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLlEG.png)

this is the YII register controller which sends welcome emails

```
 if ($model->load(\Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->register()) {
       $this->trigger(self::EVENT_AFTER_REGISTER, $event);

        $consumerKey    = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
        $consumerSecret = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

        $accessKey = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
        $accessSecret = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
        $list_id = '3857937';
            $aweber = new \AWeberAPI($consumerKey, $consumerSecret);
        try {
            $account = $aweber->getAccount($accessKey, $accessSecret);
            $account_id = $account->id;              
            $listURL = "/accounts/{$account_id}/lists/{$list_id}";
            $list = $account->loadFromUrl($listURL);

            $params = array(
                'email' => $model->email,
                'ad_tracking' => 'My_Web_Form_3',
                'name' => $model->username
            );

            $subscribers = $list->subscribers;
            $new_subscriber = $subscribers->create($params);

        } catch(AWeberAPIException $exc) {

        }           
        return $this->render('message', [
            'title'  => \Yii::t('user', 'Your account has been created'),
            'module' => $this->module,
        ]);
    }

    return $this->render('register_w', [
        'model'  => $model,
        'module' => $this->module,
    ]);
}
```